# In a generic class, method with signature '(...args: Parameters<T[K]>): void' allows instances of conflicting types to be assigned to each other

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I wrote a tiny Node style `EventEmitter` with a type parameter that describes the event names that the emitter can event as well as the type of the functions that handle each event respectively. Here's a usage demo:

```
// This interfaces describes event names and the types of their respective listeners.
interface FooEvents {
  foo: (n1: number, n2: number) => void;
  fooTwo: (o: object) => void;
  fooThree: (s: string) => void;
};

const exampleFooEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<FooEvents>();
fooEmitter.on('foo', (n: number) => console.log('Got foo', n));
fooEmitter.emit('foo', 1, 3); // console: Got foo 1 and Got foo 3

// As expected, typechecker error as 'scary' is not assignable to 'foo' | 'fooTwo' | 'fooThree'.
fooEmitter.on('scary', () => {}); 
// As expected, typechecker error as '(o: object) => void' is not assignable to type '(s: string) => void'.
fooEmitter.on('fooThree', (o: object) => console.log(o));
```

Here's the definition for `EventEmitter`:

```js
type Events<T> = {[K in keyof T]: (...args: any[]) => any; }
declare class EventEmitter<T extends Events<T>> {
    on<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, handler: T[K]): void;
    off<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, handler: T[K]): void;
    emit<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, ...args: Parameters<T[K]>): void;
}
```

Getting closer to the problem, let's add another interface that describes a different set of events:

```js
// Same names as FooEvents, but with different types for their listeners.
interface BarEvents {
  foo: (s: string) => void;
  fooTwo: (n: number) => void;
  fooThree: (o: object) => void;
}
```

and create event emitters for both types:

```
let fooEmitter = new EventEmitter<FooEvents>();
let barEmitter = new EventEmitter<BarEvents>();
```

**The problem.** I am able to assign `fooEmitter` and `barEmitter` to each other. While `FooEvents` and `BarEvents` share the same keys, their values should not be assignable to one another.

```
fooEmitter = barEmitter; // No error!
barEmitter = fooEmitter; // No error!
```

However, I found that removing the `emit` method from `EventEmitter<T>` gets me the typechecking errors I was expecting.

```js
declare class NoEmitter<T extends Events<T>> {
    on<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, handler: T[K]): void;
    off<K extends keyof T>(eventName: K, handler: T[K]): void;
    // removed emit
}

declare let fooNoEmitter: NoEmitter<FooEvents>;
declare let barNoEmitter: NoEmitter<BarEvents>;

fooNoEmitter = barNoEmitter; // Error. Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
barNoEmitter = fooNoEmitter; // Same error. Good!
```

In fact, adding any sort of method to `EventEmitter` with a type parameter of `K extends keyof T` that includes a rest argument of `Parameters<T[K]>` causes the errors that I expect to go away. Example:   `wrench<K extends keyof T>(...args: Parameters<T[K]>): void;`

**The question**. Why does this happen? The types of `emit` on `EventEmitter<FooEvents>` and `EventEmitter<BarEvents>` should ideally conflict. Even they don't, why doesn't the type checker still recognize the conflicts of the `on`/`off` methods and emit errors?

edit 1: [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzgHgCoD4oF4oDeA2gNJQCWiUA1hCAPYBmUGAugFxQAUAdHwIYAnAOYpO-RCCKsAlHhwSQAbigBfAFDqAJhADGAGyHQD-FClgJkMALblgwCIMxQIADweIt5%20ElSYsOATqUCFQ9IhoZG4eXjR0TCxYXBCWwABy-NYQnCQANFAAFhJa%20o6cGKSynHD05FpKwaFMjJEu7kixtAzM2MmpGVk5%20UWepYLllTLVtfWNIRC2wK3RHeZdCb0pvgPZUHlQfDxCopwACkKZEA6C6BUkrFhTUDV1DRrqoJBQAGL09D7Icz4IIhRh-ThcRAARk4iAArtYAEaOfKIABMsIRyMEclwOBes1BfwwAHd6BDyWFEQArPTAXH4mYNIn0DAFQQQXZcMRQFDAQSUYQM55M9SqBofcDQABCQgBqDwhEaYMp3M4fIFiCF8hFr2VxLJEMQmKRjmFBOZUBVbI5XMp9BpdPNovepWAVr%20Njs10ViAgJIsvi99kcaF%20-1SKCSMgabqgiLlix9%20D9AflweuaFlgnlUa4Mc0KozjkVCZzSccDTLxcEiqLFcEEp0Jg5UBMZigaX%20DecK083kj-kCczCESi7X7cW6iT620uQ0KxTGE3uTwtI%20aywnnXiPSSW2QOwXIxKZRYk2mevezcMrbjKq7Nc4j574dzWAaN6MUDjZZf3rPf8QycbN3wlB9uwA2t8D-SDgKrIQgOTD16CQytNHUIA)

Comment: Please share the definition of `EventEmitter` (here on Stack Overflow, not only on the playground).

Comment: Whoops--forgot the most important part. Fixed.